# How to implement styles or sass / css modules in react sticky table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying [react-sticky-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table) third party library. It is not accepted CSS or styles. but some styling or CSS elements work react-sticky-table. it is not accepting the styling fully

I want to fully access the CSS and styling properties and elements in react-sticky-table. 
So how to solve it?

If you have any other solution, please refer to it here.

package link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table

demo link
https://henrybuilt.github.io/react-sticky-table/?path=/story/basic--basic

Comment: override with same class name and add ```!important``` to the style. It works most of the time.

Comment: tried but it is not working, It accesses some style elements such as height and backgroundColor. Other styles are not worked

Comment: some CSS works and many CSS isn't working. Many normal styling works but some styling is not working.

Comment: I experienced using a react sticky table, every cell and row need to wrap styles. That is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced CSS or SASS styling is not working in react sticky table. Actually react sticky table works perfectly. If you using css / sass modules in your react app, you need to access global style of react stick table.

How to access global style? you may use `:global` pseudo selector, You will be achieved the global styles in css / sass module.

If you use normal css / sass (without module) , you don't need to specify the `:global` pseudo-selector. Because normal css / sass is global style.

Otherwise we can achieve inline css styles